# Replace all occurrences in string giving an array as a parameter

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to replace all occurrences in string giving an array as a parameter in `replace()` method.

For example:

Having this string: `"ABCDEFG"`

And having this array: `['A','D','F']`

It is possible to replace the same letters in the string with something else? Something like:

`"ABCDEFG".replace(['A','D','F'], '')`

So the final result be: `"BCEG"`

Comment: Is `"ABCDEFG".replace(/A|D|F/g, '')` would be fine, or it has to be dynamic with the array ?

Comment: Not in the `replace` method (given you don't want to touch the prototype). You could write your own function, though

Comment: @Leyffda is a dynamic array, anyway this gives me an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through your array:

```js
var str = "ABCDEFG";
['A','D','F'].forEach(c => str = str.replace(c, '*'))
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of:

```
 "ABCDEFG".replace(new RegExp(['A','D','F'].join("|")), '')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to do this from an Array.

You'll need to create a RegEx dynamically :

```js
let arr = ['A','D','F'];
let expression = arr.join('|');
let rx = new RegExp(expression, 'g');

console.log("ABCDEFG".replace(rx,''));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array as input:

```
'ABCDEF'.replace(new RegExp(['A','D','F'].join('|'), 'g'), '')
```

By using the 'g' flag, it will replace all occurrences of 'A', 'D' or 'F' in the string.

You could also do this in a simpler way:

```
'ABCDEF'.replace(/A|D|F/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general function that uses regex similar to the other answers, but allows you to pass in whatever replacement string you like:

```js
const str = 'ABCDEFG';
const arr = ['A', 'D', 'F'];

function replace(str, arr, r) {
  const regex = new RegExp(arr.join('|'), 'g');
  return str.replace(regex, p => r);
}

console.log(replace(str, arr, ''));
console.log(replace(str, arr, 'bob'));
```